# Graylog server not working

Tags: graylog

I see that after installing graylog server , I am not able to login its giving me an error as shown in the below images , I see the logs there are no issues

I have setted up the reverse proxy for graylog web interface

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address.

You've probably misconfigured the [`web_endpoint_uri`](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/blob/2.4.3/misc/graylog.conf#L134-L136) or [`rest_transport_uri`](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/blob/2.4.3/misc/graylog.conf#L83-L90) configuration setting or the `X-Graylog-Server-URL` HTTP request header (which overrides the aforementioned settings).

Also take a look at the Graylog documentation for the Graylog web interface, which has more details on the matter:
http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/configuration/web_interface.html#how-does-the-web-interface-connect-to-the-graylog-server

Comment: web_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/, web_endpoint_uri = http://127.0.0.1:9000/, rest_transport_uri = http://127.0.0.1:9000/,this is my configuration , I am getting the error as We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running on http://127.0.0.1:9000/. Please verify that the server is healthy and working correctly.

Comment: That's probably because you're not running your web browser on the same machine as Graylog. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback network address which is only accessible from the very same machine.